# Слова, начинающиеся с буквы "а"

Tags: иностранные-слова

Много лет назад зацепилась в памяти услышанная от кого-то фраза, что в русском языке нет ни одного слова, начинающегося с буквы "а", кроме слов "авось" и "авоська". Нигде больше не встречал такой информации, а зацепка осталась. Неужели действительно так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, подобную информацию (с  учетом нижеследующей оговорки) вы могли найти местах, например в "Слове о словах" Льва Успенского.
Во-вторых, это не совсем так. Правильно будет сказать, что в русском **почти** нет собственно русских слов, начинающихся с А, за исключением междометий, союзов и частиц (изначально - еше и местоимений), а также слов, от них образованных. "Авось", а значит, и "авоська", тоже можно свести к междометиям, так что в каком-то смысле даже их и выделять-то не стоит.  
Что же касается причины, то она проста до банальности. Русский язык на раннем этапе своего самостоятельного существования избегал слов, начинающихся с гласного звука.
Начальное А переходило регулярно переходило в Я, О в Е и ВО, У в ВУ (с меньшей регулярностью), Э в Е. Оставались только слова, начинающиеся с И, хотя в близкородственном украинском и оно переходило в ЙИ. Примеров не буду приводить, вы легко их найдете.

Comment: Вы просили исправлять, я исправляю: во-первых - вводное, нппример - опечатка.

Comment: Ок, спасию. Я, правда, еще не успел сам проверить.  По техническим причинам. Отвлечься пришлось.

Answer (score 1):

В  древнерусском  языке  действовал  закон  открытого  слога,  поэтому  в  заимствованных словах  перед  начальным  "а"  появлялся  протетический  j ( йот ), который  был  согласным  звуком.  С  другими  гласными  картина  та  же.

Comment: Не совсем. Начальный О часто переходил в ВО или в Е. У - в ВУ, никак не в Ю, хотя часто оставался и нетронутым.

Answer (score 0):

Азы, азбука - вполне себе русские слова.

Comment: Не совсем. Аз - это название буквы, из церковнославянского. В русском же Аз (метоимение первого лица) перешло в Яз, которое и породило нынешнее Я. 
Я, кстати, там оговаривался насчет местоимения. Именно его я и имел в виду.

Comment: Не знал, спасибо.